# UIImage Filter to detect face and convert to emoticon/smiley

Tags: ios, objective-c, filter, uiimage, emoticons

I need to generate an emoticon by capturing a photo of a person,

[image]

Lets say this is the image i capture from device (iPhone/iPad) so i need to extract/get only face(by removing background and other parts from the image) and add a filter so that this image(**UIImage**) get converted into :

1. Emoticon
2. Cartoon face like this

[image]

I need to get this thing sorted out, please share your idea or any link which has code with similar kind functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [GPUImage library](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) has a built in "Toon" filter

Comment: thanks, but how about making it as emoticon? is there any way to do it ? @ezig

Comment: You'll need to do some sort of edge/background detection. You might look into OpenCV's [support](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html) assuming you don't want to write your own edge detection.

Comment: If anyone find the perfect solution then please upload your code...Thanks.

Comment: Hi @sKhan, did you find the solution? I'm working on the same kind of project, so it would be a great help if you share the solution (if founded). Thanks!